# How to restrict access to a child SVN directory only?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, authorization, mod-dav-svn

I'm trying to configure permissions for an SVN repository accessed through Apache 2. What I want is to let anyone access the root directory, while restricting to authenticated users a child directory. Example:

```
/demo
/demo/project1
/demo/project1/sensitive-data  # This path should require user authentication.
/demo/project2
```

At first, I thought this was as simple as:

```
<Location /demo>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /home/svn/demo
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName demo
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>

<Location /demo/project1/sensitive-data>
    DAV svn
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When used through HTTP (for example with CURL), Apache conforms to the configuration: I can access:

- http://example.com/demo/,
- http://example.com/demo/project1/ and:
- http://example.com/demo/project2/,

and I get, as expected, a `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` when trying to retrieve http://example.com/demo/project1/sensitive-data.

On the other hand, doing:

- `svn checkout http://example.com/demo/ .` or:
- `svn checkout http://example.com/demo/project1/ .`

retrieves the whole directory tree, including `demo/project1/sensitive-data`.

At least, `svn checkout http://example.com/demo/project1/sensitive-data/ .` requests for a password.

How should I configure the permissions to restrict the access to `sensitive-data` directory when doing `svn checkout http://example.com/demo/ .`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Location /demo/project1/sensitive-data>` block is irrelevant when doing a checkout: it is used only when accessing http://example.com/demo/project1/sensitive-data directly, which is the reason why HTTP requests result in `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` and a checkout of this particular directory requires authentication.

The proper way to configure path-based authorization is [explained in Subversion documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html):

1. `<Location /demo>` points to an access file:

   ```
   <Location /demo>
       ...
       AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/access.conf
       ...
   </Location>
   ```
2. The access file defines who can access the specific files and directories. Basic example:

   ```
   [/]
   * = r                  # Everyone should be able to access the repository.

   [/demo/project1/sensitive-data] # Note that there is no trailing slash.
   * =                    # Nobody should access the sensitive directory.
   ```

Comment: Can this be used similarly in reverse? I want to give guest access to a sub-directory only, and disallow "guest" to browse the rest of the repository.

Or maybe the easiest way would be to just create a separate repository?

Comment: @Zack: I don't have a test environment right now, but I believe that yes, you can do that. Also relevant: [What are the permissions to set on SVN root?](http://serverfault.com/q/538036/39827)